# smooth transition with ng-show/hide in angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am some elements in a list that I can hide/show by clicking on a button:

```
ul
  li(ng-show="some_condition1") item1
  li(ng-show="some_condition2") item2
  li(ng-show="some_condition3") item3
  li(ng-show="some_condition4") item4
```

When `some_condition1` turn false, `item1` disappear and all the remaining item abruptly move up. Is there a way to have them slide up?

I have thought of using css transitions with something like this: `transition: all ease 0.2s` but as my items properties are not touched it doesn't work...

Comment: They have some code that uses animations on the ngHide documentation page https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

Answer (score 0):

try using following code:

```
var $item = $(this).closest('li');
$item.hide('slow', function(){ $item.remove(); });
```

Comment: thanks but this is not what I am looking for. I can fadeout the item but the problem is how to make a smooth transition for the items below when they move up